# Flatness of modules over dual numbers

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, flatness, affine-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, affine complex surface, and $M$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Denote by $D:=\mbox{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2))$ and $X_D:=X \times_{\mathbb{C}} D$, the trivial deformation of $X$. Let 
$$0 \to M \to M' \to M \to 0$$
be a short exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Under the natural morphism $$ \mathcal{O}_{X_D} \to \mathcal{O}_X,$$ we can consider any $\mathcal{O}_X$-module as an $\mathcal{O}_{X_D}$-module. My question is: Is $M'$ going to be $D$-flat, considered as an $\mathcal{O}_{X_D}$-module?

Comment: Your formulation is unclear.  Is the action of $t$ on $M'$ intended to be the composition of the epimorphism $M'\to M$ and the monomorphism $M\to M'$?

Comment: As worded I think Chen is not asking for that, and so the answer is no.

Comment: @PhilTosteson.  I agree with you.  As formulated, the OP seems to be asking whether $M'$, considered as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, is then flat when considered as an $\mathcal{O}_{X_D}$-module, and the answer to that question is "no".  However, if the OP changes the $\mathcal{O}_{X_D}$-module structure as in my comment, then $M'$ is flat as an $\mathcal{O}_{X_D}$-module.

Comment: @JasonStarr and Phil: Thank you for the comments. I was considering $M'$ as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.